# Cannot access list, created in index.cshtml.cs, in the index.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, info

I'm trying to create a simple site, but when I try to access a list in the `index.cshtml`, which I created in the `index.cshtml.cs`, it says it doesn't exist.

Content of the `index.cshtml.cs` file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Proiectss.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public List<ClientInfo> listClients = new List<ClientInfo>();
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
    
        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            ViewData["listClients"] = HttpContext.Features.Get<Proiectss.Pages.Clients.IndexModel>().listClients;
        }
    
        public void OnGet()
        {
            try
            {
                String connectionString = "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=spital;Integrated Security=True";

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    string sql = "SELECT * FROM clients";

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while(reader.Read())
                            {
                                ClientInfo clientInfo = new ClientInfo();
                                clientInfo.id = "" + reader.GetInt32(0);
                                clientInfo.name = reader.GetString(1);
                                clientInfo.email = reader.GetString(2);
                                clientInfo.phone = reader.GetString(3);
                                clientInfo.adress = reader.GetString(4);
                                clientInfo.created_at = reader.GetDateTime(5).ToString();
    
                                listClients.Add(clientInfo); 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public class ClientInfo
    {
        public String id;
        public String name;
        public string email;
        public String phone;
        public String adress;
        public String created_at;
    }
}
```

Content of the `index.cshtml`:

```
@page
@model Proiectss.Pages.Clients.IndexModel
@{

}
<br>

<h2>List of Clients</h2>

<a href="/Clients/Create">`New Client`</a>

            ID
            Name
            Email
            Phone
            Adress
            Created At
            Action
    
    @foreach (var item in Model.listClients) /* this is where I get the error */
    {
            @item.id
            @item.name
            @item.email
            @item.phone
            @item.adress
            @item.created_at
    }
```

I am trying to access the list, but I can't.

Comment: Add return Page() in your OnGet method.

Answer (score 1):

Within your index.cshtml, you are defining your model as `Proiectss.Pages.Clients.IndexModel`, but the namespace in your index.cstml.cs is `Proiectss.Pages`.
Meaning that the model that you are using in your `cshtml` file is not the same as the one you posted in the `index.cshtml.cs`.

Furthermore, you do not need this line in your 'Ctor of `IndexModel`

```
ViewData["listClients"] = HttpContext.Features.Get<Proiectss.Pages.Clients.IndexModel>().listClients;
```

The `OnGet()` method will be called by the framework and when your used model in your razor page matches the class that you posted here, the public property `listClients` will be filled and usable within your razor page.

How it looks like to me, is that you have two `IndexModel` classes and are attempting to use the wrong one.
My suggestion would be to move the `listClients` property and `OnGet()` method from the `Proiectss.Pages.IndexModel` class to the `Proiectss.Pages.Clients.IndexModel` class, then everything should work as you expect them to.